# What's the difference between get_site_option and get_blog_option?

Tags: multisite

I'm trying to understand the difference between [get_site_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option) and [get_blog_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_option).

Are *blog* and *site* two different things? Apologies if this question seems basic, but when referring to a WordPress website, I've always used both terms very loosely (to mean the same thing). I'm now wondering if there is a difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**`get_option()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) returns an option for the *current* blog.

In single site installation, the current blog is the only blog. So get `get_option()` returns the option for it.

---

[**`get_site_option()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_option/) is used to retrieve an option network-wide. It means that you can get the same option from any site of the network.

When this function is used in single installation, it *normally* returns the same thing of `get_option()`. The value may change because `get_site_option()` trigger filter hooks that are not triggered by `get_option()`.

Note that once the `$wpdb->options` table is blog-specific, network-wide options are stored in the [`$wpdb->sitemeta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_sitemeta) table, that is specific of multisite installations.

---

[**`get_blog_option()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_option/) is the only among the three functions that doesn't receive the option name as 1st argument, but its 1st argument is `$blog_id`.

In fact, it is used in multisite installations to retrieve an option from a specific blog whose the id is known.

What this function does is:

```
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
$value = get_option( $option, $default );
restore_current_blog();

return $value;
```

If `$blog_id` is the same of current blog id, WordPress just skips the `switch_to_blog` part and just calls `get_option()`.

This function is defined in the file [`wp-includes/ms-blogs.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php) that is loaded only for multisite installation, so `get_blog_option()` is not defined in single site installations.

Answer (score 7):

`get_site_option()` - Gets a network wide option. This option is usually added in the Network Admin Settings section of a multisite set-up. If I had 50 sites, it would be a pain to go to 50 different sites and set the same option value. Instead I could set the option value once and have it apply across the network for all sites. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option

`get_blog_option()` - Lets you get the value of an option for a specific site. One example might be to get the value of a user specific option for each site. So I could get all of the sites that the user belongs too, loop over the list of site IDs, and use `get_blog_option()` passing the `blog_id` and option name and get back the result. It's a convenience function that pretty much does the following:

`switch_to_blog( $id );
$value = get_option( $option_name );
restore_current_blog();`

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_option

**tl;dr:** `get_site_option()` gets a network wide value, `get_blog_option()` gets a specific value for a given site without needing to switch to that site first on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Although `get_option()` may retrieve the blog option on network sites, sometimes the network filters override the site option.

For example: `users_can_register` for the site will always be overridden by the network setting.

To retrieve the site option, sometimes you'll need to remove any network filters which are located in the ms-default-filters.php file in the WP Core.

```
remove_filter( 'option_users_can_register', 'users_can_register_signup_filter' ); // ignore network override
$registration = get_option( 'users_can_register');
```