# How to set an option for all sites in my Multisite network?

Tags: multisite, options

I have a multisite instance of WordPress with almost 100 sites. I need to set an option for a network-wide installed plugin but I don't want to go to each site dashboard to set this option by hand. How could I do ?

The option I want to change is a classic option, not a network-wide one. It comes from a plugin that I did not write. Want I need it to change the value of that classic option for all sites in my network at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excuse me if I'm misunderstanding you, but aren't the functions `add_site_option()`, `update_site_option()` and `get_site_option()` pretty much, they fall back to single site functions, if not used in a multisite environment, only there for the purpose of having network-wide options.

---

Update:

Regarding your need to change a single site option for all sites in your network. Get all sites of the network with [`wp_get_sites()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites), which returns an array of arrays. You can use the array to loop through your single sites in your multisite installation. Make use of [`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) while looping against the `$blog_ids`. In between the loop after switching and before restoring, use the single site options functions `add_option()`, `update_option()` and `get_option()` as needed.

Comment: +1. For more info http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181219/whats-the-difference-between-get-site-option-and-get-blog-option/181231#181231

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The option I want to change is a classic option, not a network-wide one. It comes from a plugin that I did not write. Want I need it to change the value of that classic option for all sites in my network at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WP-CLI to do this now:

```
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp --url=% option update my_option my_value
```

Simply change `my_option` and `my_value` according to your needs.

Ref: https://danielbachhuber.com/tip/run-wp-cli-command-wordpress-multisite/

Edit: This doesn't work for complex serialized string values... instead, an easy workaround is temporarily setting your option value to something easy like `lolcow` and then using the search and replace operator in WP-CLI to input seralized data.

First run:

```
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp --url=% option update my_option lolcow
```

And then:

```
wp search-replace --network 'lolcow' 'a:1:{s:1:"ex_key";s:2:"account";s:3:"ex_value";s:4:"346345734";}' --all-tables
```

Ref: https://slickstack.io/forum/topic/how-can-i-update-settings-for-all-sites-in-wp-multisite-network